# Runtime-NZEC error in codechef question REDONE

Tags: python, python-3.x, pycharm

When i submit this it shows NZEC error on Codechef. I am able to run it on pycharm and even on the codechef compiler using my own inputs(mentioned below)
but codechef is not accepting this. Please help me i am new on codechef

here t is the test cases. I had to put the test cases inside the array of the input because i don't know how to input an integer and an array in a single line input

```
import array
a=list(map(int,input().split()))
t=a[0]
a.pop(0)
for i in range(t):
    n=a[i]
    arr=array.array('i',[])
    for i in range(n):
        arr.append(i+1)
    while(n>1):
        x=arr[0]
        y=arr[n-1]
        arr.pop(0)
        arr.pop()
        z=x+y+(x*y)
        arr.append(z)
        n-=1
    print(arr[0])
```

on pycharm using:
input:
3 1 2 4
output:
1
5
119

Answer (score 0):

You are doing a mistake while reading input.
There is a difference between reading space separated input and multiline input in python as shown below.

```
3 1 2 4
```

and

```
3
1
2
4
```

use this to read input in python:

```
for i in range(input()):
    n = input()

    ... use the value of n here
```

Comment: i previously tried input via different line(i.e. after every input i had to press enter) but it was also showing NZEC and i read on stackoverflow that codechef puts a single line input thats why i changed it